# How to Update Record of Sql Server table in Loop matching condition?

Tags: sql-server, loops, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I am concerned that if the update query goes wrong it will impact whole table.

I am writing here query to show what data I have and how I will have to update it,

```
SELECT BuildingId,VisitNumber,Id,TasksId,Status,GregorianDate
FROM Visit where status=5 and BuildingId in (7,8,9,10)
Group by BuildingId,Id,TasksId,Status,VisitNumber,GregorianDate
order by BuildingId,GregorianDate asc

BuildingId  VisitNumber Id  TasksId Status  GregorianDate
7            Visit_U_1  169     79    5     2018-04-09
7            Visit_U_1  1217    506   5     2018-08-01
7            Visit_U_1  2162    775   5     2019-01-09
8            Visit_U_1  148     72    5     2018-04-10
8            Visit_U_1  2206    783   5     2019-01-08
9            Visit_U_1  161     76    5     2018-04-10
9            Visit_U_1  1175    489   5     2018-07-30
9            Visit_U_1  2128    770   5     2019-01-08
```

As we can see results of query it is not necessary that we have three records for building id it can be 3,4 or any number of times. Similarly GregorianDates are not fixed.

I want to update VisitNumbr sequence like in case of BuildingId '7'. Its first visit must be 'Visit_U_1' than second will be 'Visit_U_2' ans so on according to the GregorianDate.

Similarly for building '8'. Again visit number become 'Visit_U_1', 'Visit_U_2' and so on according to GregorianDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the column 'GregorianDate' is a DateTime data type filed. If so, this following query will serve your purpose-

```
UPDATE V
SET    VisitNumber  = 'Visit_U_' + N
FROM   visit V
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    BuildingId,
    GregorianDate,
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BuildingID ORDER BY GregorianDate) AS VARCHAR) N
    FROM   visit
    WHERE  BuildingId IN (7, 8, 9,10)
    AND  status=5
) VN
ON  V. BuildingId = VN.BuildingId
AND V. GregorianDate = VN.GregorianDate
WHERE  V.BuildingId IN (7, 8, 9,10)
AND  V.status=5
```

Note: To generate row_number(), this is required that you apply the order by method on GregorianDate field. The smaller value in this field indicates the Visit number should be the lesser one compare to the next/later visit date.

Comment: getting same error "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: let me check @nkRabbani you really made my day it working awsome

Comment: sorry i dont have enogh reputation so i can only tick your answer

Comment: Its my pleasure that my script helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using `substring` and `row_number`

**Select Query**

you want output as below `Visit_U_1,Visit_U_2, Visit_U_3`  So I am removing the last digit from Vist column and added it with the rownumber. This is done using `Sunstring` and `row_number()` function. Convert the row_number to `nvarchar` to resolve the error you are getting.

```
 substring(VisitNumber,0,len(VisitNumber)-1) + convert(nvarchar(50), row_number()over (partition by BuildingID order by BuildingID) ) visit_new
```

-

```
SELECT BuildingId,VisitNumber,Id,TasksId,Status,GregorianDate,row_number()over (partition by BuildingID order by BuildingID)srno,
substring(VisitNumber,0,len(VisitNumber)-1) + row_number()over (partition by BuildingID order by BuildingID) visit_new
FROM Visit 
where status=5 
and BuildingId in (7,8,9,10)
Group by BuildingId,Id,TasksId,Status,VisitNumber,GregorianDate
order by BuildingId,GregorianDate asc
```

**Update Query**

```
Update Visit
set Visit.VisitNumber = a.visit_new
FROM Visit 
inner join (
            SELECT   BuildingId,VisitNumber,Id,TasksId,Status,GregorianDate,row_number()over (partition by BuildingID order by GregorianDate )srno,
                     substring(VisitNumber,0,len(VisitNumber)-1) + convert(nvarchar(50), row_number()over (partition by BuildingID order by GregorianDate) )
            FROM     Visit  
            where    status=5 
            and      BuildingId in (7,8,9,10)
) a on a.status = Visit.status and a.BuildingId = visit.BuildingId
where status=5 
and BuildingId in (7,8,9,10)
```

> **Test this code before updating your live data.**

Comment: i do not understand update query is for updating record but what we are doing in select query ?

Comment: i get this error while running select query "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint"

Comment: It is too long to comment so modified the answer.

Comment: thanks for your cooperation it is working fine but just one thing is showing visitnumber in select query in this format "Visit_U1". how to just add under score after U ?

Comment: "substring(VisitNumber,0,len(VisitNumber)-1)" here i replace -1 by -0 it works finew

Comment: use concat function.                                
 Concat (substring(VisitNumber,0,len(VisitNumber)-1),'_') + convert(nvarchar(50), row_number()over (partition by BuildingID order by BuildingID) ) visit_new

Comment: i understand details you mention above but how row number is again going to 1 when we get new building id?

Comment: partition by BuildingID in Row_Number() will set row number to 1 for new building ID

Comment: using select it is showing correct data but in update without using groupby and order by it will update visitnumber sequence that might be latest date first.

Comment: Use your select query as derived table. Join it with Visit table and then update.

Comment: while running update qurey with groupby and order by getting error "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: I have modified the update query. see if it is working.

Comment: set Visit.VisitNumber = a.visit_new

Comment: i just added Visit.status and Visit.BuildingId at the end of update query it was showing it anonymous after running giving error "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified"

Comment: you can remove the order by clause since the row_number() has order by clause. you can mention   GregorianDate in row_number() order by clause.

Comment: thanks for your time and cooperation you really help me out. I used rabbani solution it is working fine